# Search-box in Bootstrap navbar jumps down one row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to implement a right-floated search-box in my navbar, but when I resize the browser-window the search-box jumps down one row. I want it to stay to the right and not jump down one row. How can I do that? This is my navbar-code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navmenu justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand themefont" href="/">Försvarshögskolan</a>
    <div class="input-group justify-content-end">
        <form name="form" class="form-inline" ng-submit="vm.anonymousSearch()" role="form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Svara anonymt med pin..." name="search" id="search" ng-model="vm.search.input" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); color: lightgrey; border-color: grey;">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary anonymous-search" type="submit">Sök</button>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping down is caused by responsive collapsing. With class `navbar-expand-lg` such responsive collapsing happens when your resized browser-window is less than 992px in width (because of the `-lg` suffix). Change mentioned class to `navbar-expand` so that your search-box stay always to the right:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navmenu justify-content-between">
```